# Design CMOS comparator

Tags: mosfet, cmos, comparator

I made the circuit. like this paper,
[image]

But It's not working.
[image]
When you insert the AC input, a square waveform should appear.
I can not interpret the circuit well.

If you know anything, please answer me. Thanks for reading.

Comment: Seems that VOUT pin doesn't have any reference. I think that you need to place a GND point. Because the oscilloscope cannot know which point is GND

Comment: Start by reporting Node voltages

Comment: I added the gnd and load resistance.

Comment: Have you properly connected VDD? According to your schematic you have not and the DC voltage is 0.

Comment: You are missing solder dots where the figure does not bridge wires over, e.g. in wire intersections that look like '+' it means they are connected. You should add a link/reference to the paper. A few things are not obvious about the intended use.

Comment: Where is the source (Vdd) of the circuit?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to pull currents out of the (input) Nchannel sources.

Comment: Your Opinion, MN7 and MN8 do not wrok?

Comment: Sorry. I did't understand it well.

Comment: Use 2 voltage sources to drive the 2 inputs. What currents flow?

Comment: This circuit is comparator.